# Change one column with one of multiple strings from another column if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I want to populate one column with a string (one of many) contained in another column (if it is contained in that column)

Right now I can do it by repeating the line of code for every different string, I'm looking for the more efficient way of doing it. I have about a dozen in total.

```
df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('g/mL'),'units'] = 'g/mL'
df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('mPa.s'),'units'] = 'mPa.s'
df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('mN/m'),'units'] = 'mN/m'
```

I don't know how to make it to check

```
df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('g/mL|mPa.s|mN/m'),'units'] = ...
```

And then make it equal to the one that is contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['this is test g/mL', 'this is test2 mPa.s', 'this is test3 mN/m']})

               column1
0    this is test g/mL
1  this is test2 mPa.s
2   this is test3 mN/m
```

```
df['units'] = df['column1'].str.extract('(g/mL|mPa.s|mN/m)')

               column1  units
0    this is test g/mL   g/mL
1  this is test2 mPa.s  mPa.s
2   this is test3 mN/m   mN/m
```

Answer (score 1):

Use loop with `str.contains`:

```
L = ['g/mL', 'mPa.s', 'mN/m']
for val in L:
    df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains(val),'units'] = val
```

Or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with list of all possible values:

```
L = ['g/mL', 'mPa.s', 'mN/m']
df['units'] = df['column1'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(L) + ')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) you can exactly do that using the `regex=True` parameter!

`df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('g/mL|mPa.s|mN/m', regex=True),'units'] = ...`

Comment: How do you make it = the character it matched?